# How to change fields label to a specific language in django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, multilingual

I am using Python 3 and Django 1.10. 
I have a model named `Company`. It has a field called `title`. I'm trying to save the company title in two languages but I don't want to separate them into `title_en` and `title_fa`. I want to save both of them using `Json` in the Company field. How can I make these changes before saving ?

I also added this model to the admin panel so I can see the fields in that page.
I want to translate `title` label (in the admin panel) and other fields in that form. 
For example if the language is English: it shows me the title as a label, if it set to fa(persian) it gives me the translation.
How can I set my language file to change them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

 class MyModel(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(_('mymodeltitle'), max_length=80)
```

Do a make message. Translate. Compile messages. It should be translated in the admin.

For translations in Django :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/

Comment: why should we use lazy ? whats wrong then with ugettext ? @Audrey-Rose

Comment: regular ugettext has given me trouble in the past when you're in different parts of the application. settings vs models vs signals vs urls etc. It was simpler to just go with lazy when I know that lazy works when I translate urls in the urls.py files. I haven't had an issue since

Comment: It shouldn't give you issues in your admin situation

Comment: I also just realized your question touched 2 concepts. This solution solves the second part, but for the first, we've always used title_en and title_fr if we had to store the titles in the database, instead of just translating a label.

Comment: Thanks... got it @Audrey-Rose